# Delete from a table after update in another table causes an error in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, sql-delete, mysql-error-1442

I have two table in a MySQL database: 'users' and 'subscription' in the table 'users', each users have a subscriptionID which is the ID of a line in 'subscriptions' or NULL. I need to create an update trigger on 'users' that delete the rows in 'subscriptions' where the new value of subscriptionID is set to null.

Here is my trigger :

```
CREATE TRIGGER `trg_DeleteSubscriptions` AFTER UPDATE ON `users`
FOR EACH ROW IF (NEW.subscriptionID <=> NULL) THEN 
DELETE FROM subscriptions s WHERE s.subscriptionID = OLD.subscriptionID; 
END IF
```

There is no problem at the creation of my trigger, however I have a recursive event that execute this query :

```
UPDATE users SET AccountState = 2, subscriptionID = null WHERE UserID IN
(SELECT * from (SELECT u.UserID FROM users u INNER JOIN subscriptions a ON
u.subscriptionID = a.subscriptionID WHERE a.EndDate < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as c)
```

and cause an error : **#1442 - Can't update table 'subscriptions' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.**

> (I know that the query is strange with the `(select * from (select ..)
>   as c)`, but that was to fix another problem where i couldn't update
>   the 'users' table because it was used in the subquery, by creating a
>   alias / temp table)

I don't understand what is the problem since the trigger is called from the 'users' table and the delete is made in 'subscriptions' ??

UPDATE : I'm pretty sure that the problem is caused by the event's query and not the trigger itself, since i tested with that simple query `'UPDATE users SET SubscriptionID = null WHERE UserID = 24` and the trigger executed correctly without error...

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Well, lets suppose that the user #1 have a subscriptionID  #5, and the subscription #5 have an endDate of 2018-07-04 16:29:28. The query is supposed to set 'null' to the subscriptionID of our user #1 (because EndDate < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) and execute the trigger that would delete the subscription #5 from the table 'subscriptions' (because we set NULL to user #1's subscriptionID)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a documented restriction in MySQL.

The SQL statement referencing table `subscriptions` is causing a trigger to be fired.

So the trigger is not allowed to modify the contents of the `subscriptions` table.

If the trigger attempts to apply a change to `subscriptions` table, MySQL raises an error.

This restriction is documented in the MySQL Reference Manual.

Comment: Thanks ! Do you have an idea of what I could do to achieve what I want ?

Comment: Could i solve this problem by creating and using a view or a temp table instead of my subquery ??

Comment: If we need to use a TRIGGER, then we would need to remove the reference to the `subscriptions` table from the statement that causes the trigger to be fired. We could create a temporary table, and populate that with a query from subscriptions, and then reference the temporary table in the UPDATE statement. But it's not clear why we need to use a trigger to perform the operation. My preference would be to avoid the trigger, and perform the DELETE operation in the same context as the UPDATE statement.

Comment: Thanks ! We chose to create a trigger because there is several place in the application where we set null to the subscription (not just in the event) and we wanted to delete the rows in 'subscriptions' automatically instead of writing two query each times